# Awkward arc4random results

Tags: objective-c, random, arc4random

I'm using this code, where 'length' value is '50'.

```
newX = (arc4random()%(lenght+1)) - (lenght/2);
newY = (arc4random()%(lenght+1)) - (lenght/2);
NSLog(@"Creature Move X:%f, Y:%f", newX, newY);
```

But in the debugger I get things like:

```
2012-01-02 21:10:50.794 Kipos[28833:207] Creature Move X:4294967296.000000, Y:4294967296.000000
2012-01-02 21:10:50.896 Kipos[28833:207] Creature Move X:4294967296.000000, Y:12.000000
```

What is happening?

`newX` and `newY` are floats:

```
float newX;
float newY;
```

Comment: Very strange... what's the type of '`lenght`' (typo btw), and can you NSLog it at the same time as this log?

Comment: Length (typo *facepalm*) is an int. Already solved. But thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`arc4random` returns an *unsigned* int (and presumably `length` is also unsigned). Change your code to e.g.

```
newX = (float)((int)(arc4random() % (length + 1))) - (length / 2));
```

in order to avoid overflow when you subtract.

Note that I have also added an explicit float cast for the result, which is not strictly necessary but it makes the code a little more self-explanatory.

Comment: Out of interest where did you look to find that out? My lazy googling couldn't find the return type of `%`.

Comment: So I guess here `length` was also unsigned? Otherwise the compiler should have converted the left operand to a signed int before doing the subtraction? Or do I have this wrong?

Comment: It worked! Thanks!

It also worked Paul.s suggestion (change '2' for '2.00'):


    `newX = arc4random()%(length+1) - (length/2.00);`
    `newY = arc4random()%(length+1) - (length/2.00);`

Comment: @Paul.s: it's just the usual type rules for expressions in C - `unsigned % unsigned` will give an unsigned result

Comment: Btw, instead of using %f in the NSLog, what would you suggest?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `%f` but I prefer `%g` for logging and debug etc

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help :) It was driving me crazy!